# getting results from sql join using perl

Tags: perl

this works

```
TABLE users

userid  firstname   lastname
1        JOHN          DEO
2        JANE          DEO

TABLE msg

msg_id    msg_from     msg_to      received   
1         userid(1)    userid(2)   null
```

```
$janedeo_id = 2;


my $data = $DBH->prepare("SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
  ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = ? 
  AND M.received IS NULL");
$data->execute($janedeo_id);
while (my $row = $data->fetchrow_hashref) {
    foreach $row ( @$data) {
        ($userid, $snd_firstname, $snd_lastname) = @$data;
}
}
my $templ    = <<START_HTML;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
+" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
[% FOREACH name IN list %]
<p>userid    [% name.0 %] </p>
<p>firstname [% name.1 %] </p>
<p>lastname  [% name.2 %] </p>
[% END %]
</body>
</html>

START_HTML

$template->process (\$templ, { list => \@$data })
        or die $template->error;
```

this doesn't work. when i try to add age city country and results it fails cant works

```
TABLE users

userid   firstname    lastname
1         JOHN         DEO
2         JANE         DEO

TABLE msg

msg_id    msg_from     msg_to      received   age  city  country
1         userid(1)    userid(2)   null       26   any   any
```

```
$janedeo_id = 2;


my $data = $DBH->prepare("SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, SND.age, SND.city, SND.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
  ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = ? 
  AND M.received IS NULL");
$data->execute($janedeo_id);
while (my $row = $data->fetchrow_hashref) {
    foreach $row ( @$data) {
        ($userid, $snd_firstname, $snd_lastname, $snd.age, $snd.city, $snd.country) = @$data;
}
}
my $templ    = <<START_HTML;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
[% FOREACH name IN list %]
<p>userid    [% name.0 %] </p>
<p>firstname [% name.1 %] </p>
<p>lastname  [% name.2 %] </p>
<p>city      [% name.3 %] </p>
<p>age       [% name.4 %] </p>
<p>country   [% name.5 %] </p>
[% END %]
</body>
</html>

START_HTML

$template->process (\$templ, { list => \@$data })
        or die $template->error;
```

am failing to get results when i try to add city age country to table msg and getting them printed out. am just getting blank response. even the script just printing error. cant find anything in database. so am just confused i don't know the problem

Comment: `$snd.age` is a syntax error.

Comment: any example. that would be good coz i tried a millions way but failed. even i got more examples from different people but all failed

Comment: The real solution is to stop copy/pasting random "examples" from different sources without understanding the code. For example, why do you have that `foreach $row` loop in your program at all? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Crossposted from https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1223472

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird:

```
while (my $row = $data->fetchrow_hashref) {
    foreach $row ( @$data) {
        ($userid, $snd_firstname, $snd_lastname, $snd.age, $snd.city, $snd.country) = @$data;
    }
}
```

You fetch one row from the result as a hash reference. You than iterate over `@$data` which is a statement handle - this can't work. Use the fetched `$row` in the loop.

Also, `.` is the concatenation operator. What do you mean by `$snd.city`?

You can use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) to see what structure is returned:

```
use Data::Dumper;

...
while (my $row = $data->fetchrow_hashref) {
    print Dumper $row;
}
```

Here's a standalone example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use DBI;
use Template;

# Fake the database
my $dbh = 'DBI'->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:', "", "");
$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE USERS (id INT, firstname VARCHAR(20), lastname VARCHAR(20), age INT, city VARCHAR(20), country VARCHAR(20))');
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(1, "John", "Doe", 30, "Mumbai", "India")');
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(2, "Jane", "Doe", 20, "New York", "USA")');

$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE msg (id INT, msg_from VARCHAR(20), msg_to VARCHAR(20), received BOOL)');
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO msg VALUES (1, 2, 1, NULL)');

# Template.
my $templ = << '__HTML__';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
[% FOREACH user IN list %]
<p>userid    [% user.id %] </p>
<p>firstname [% user.firstname %] </p>
<p>lastname  [% user.lastname %] </p>
<p>city      [% user.city %] </p>
<p>age       [% user.age %] </p>
<p>country   [% user.country %] </p>
[% END %]
</body>
</html>
__HTML__


my $data = $dbh->prepare(<< '__SQL__');
    SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, age, u.city, u.country
    FROM msg as m
    JOIN users as u
        ON u.id = m.msg_from
    WHERE m.msg_to = ?
        AND m.received IS NULL
__SQL__

$data->execute(1);
my @output;
while (my $row = $data->fetchrow_hashref) {
    push @output, $row;
}
'Template'->new->process (\$templ, { list => \@output })
        or die $templ->error;
```

Comment: any example. that would be good coz i tried a millions way but failed. even i got more examples from different people but all failed

Comment: Standalone example created.

Comment: this is wat confuse people and everyone do it in his on way where by cant be helped. the city, age and country are in table msg not table users. i have a reason why i made it like that. the problem is not getting info. the problem is selecting from table msg  to bring these city age and country. try to add these columns city age and country to table msg not users. i appreciate your help

Comment: @mikejoe: Then you SQL query is wrong. Please try to help us to help you by providing all the details and trying not to confuse us.

Comment: i already posted the sql query. but everyone is bypassing the problem and give me other alternative way. which i dont want

Comment: `TABLE users

userid   firstname    lastname
1         JOHN         DEO
2         JANE         DEO

TABLE msg

msg_id    msg_from     msg_to      received   age  city  country
1         userid(1)    userid(2)   null       26   any   any
my $data = $DBH->prepare("SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, SND.age, SND.city, SND.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
  ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = ? 
  AND M.received IS NULL");
$data->execute($janedeo_id);
while (my $row = $data->fetchrow_hashref) {
       
}
}`

Comment: @mikejoe Please edit your original question if you’re going to include additional info. Nobody wants to read an unformatted wall of text in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You seem very, very confused. I don't think you are actually showing us the code that you are running. Look at this code:

```
my $data = $DBH->prepare("SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, 
                                 SND.lastname
                            FROM msg as M
                            JOIN users as SND 
                              ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
                           WHERE M.msg_to = ? 
                             AND M.received IS NULL");

$data->execute($janedeo_id);
while (my $row = $data->fetchrow_hashref) {
    foreach $row ( @$data) {
        ($userid, $snd_firstname, $snd_lastname,
         $snd.age, $snd.city, $snd.country) = @$data;
    }
}
```

This is your first code example - the code that you claim works. But it can't possibly work.

You have a variable called `$data` which contains your DBI statement handle (I know that because it's returned from a `$DBH->prepare()` call). It would be more usual to call this variable `$sth`.

You, correctly, call `execute()` on this object and then start to call `fetchrow_hashref()` in a loop. You store the hash reference you get in a variable called `$row`. So far so good.

But then it all goes wrong.

You ignore the hash reference you have and overwrite it with the data that is stored in `$data`. But there's no data in `$data` - it's a statement handle. You treat it as an array reference (`@$data`) but it's not an array reference, so this would throw a fatal runtime error.

You then ignore the second value you have put in `$row` and switch to using individual variables to, presumably, store the data that you're getting back from the database. Once again, you treat `$data` as an array reference and once again, it won't work and will throw a fatal runtime error. Oh, and you're using variable names (for example, `$snd.age`) which are invalid in Perl and which would almost certainly give you a syntax error.

By claiming that this code works, you are wasting our time. It doesn't work. It doesn't even compile. We are very happy to help people here, but you need to show us actual code that we can run.

I don't know what your programming background is. But in order to be successful in this career, you are going to have to pay a lot more attention to detail.

Answer (score -1):

i got this fixed by doing

```
SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, M.age, M.city, M.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid -1'
AND M.received IS NULL
```

Comment: `msg_to` contains numbers, but you compare it to strings in `WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid -1'` ? This cannot be right.

Comment: msg_to ya. contains numbers bt no problem with that i just remove to WHERE M.msg_to = ?. it was just fixing sql query first to move to next step